# Matching type definition file with the module's version

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm

How do I know that the right version of the definition file was downloaded?
Right now I am trying to install
@types/react-router
and the latest version is 5.1.18
the version of react-rooter is 5.2.1

how to know if @types/react-router 5.1.18 is compatible with react-rooter is 5.2.1?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: there is no code here. I have installed  react-rooter is 5.2.1 and now I would like to install type definitions for it. But it seems type definitions do not follow the same versioning.